# Define sequelize associations in separated file

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize and sequelize-auto packages to manage my models, but everytime that I need to re-generete the models as result from a modification in the database I need to redefine te associations all over again since the associations are defined in classMethods in model file.

There is some way do define the associations in different file?

Comment: Why not use the [migrations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html) feature?

Comment: I'm kinda new to sequelize and migrations is not something that I have already used.Sequelize-auto in the other hand seems natural to me since I'm working with databases for a long time. For what I know at the moment in migrations I cannot use it in a existing database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came with a similar solution, but seems even simpler. Each model is defined in a separate file imported to the associations file where models are connected in a function. That function is imported, executed and assigned to a variable in the server file. It works.

associations.js file:

```
Model1 = require('./Model1')
Model2 = require('./Model2')

const setAssociations = function() {
   Model1.belongsTo(Model2)
}
module.exports = setAssociations;
```

server.js file:

```
const Associations = require('./models/associations')();
```

Comment: What should I do with the newly created Associations const ? Should I assign  Associations to something?

Comment: You don't need to do anything with it. You just need to enforce execution of the imported function and storing the result in the const is sufficient and simplest. The whole setup will work.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found at the present time is to create a file like 'associations.js' outside the sequelize models folder whith content like this:

```
module.exports = function (models) {

  models.model1.hasMany(models.model2, {
    onDelete: 'cascade',
    foreignKey: 'model1123'
  });

  models.model1.Instance.prototype.getTimes = function () {
    return this.x * 100;
  }
};
```

In this file you will setup all the relations and the instance methods for each model in ypur aplication.
As you can see you need to pass the models object for it to work, for this in your models/index.js:

```
'use strict'

...

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

require('../utils/associations')(db);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Just require the module passing the sequelize object after it has been initialized.

Hope it can help someone else.